# save current view to bitmap WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmapimage

I just started to WP7 Dev, and I would like a bit of help on solving this:
I have a `Canvas` in wich I have 2 `StackPanels` where I draw like 10 `Rectangle`. So my question is, how do I save the canvas to a `Bitmap`?

here is what I want to achieve, that from this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Any help that points me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347331%28v=vs.95%29) and then call it's [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method with the UIElement you want to render to it.

Comment: so, something like:
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(GridLayout,null);
bitmap.Render(GridLayout, null);
would do it?